# Amount of matches in two Django ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, django-models

In my application I would like to determine similarity between objects.
The objects have a few ManyToMany fields and the amount of matching values in that list would give an indication of the similarity. (e.g. one song might be similar to another if it has a lot of common artists, genres or producers)

```
class Song:
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    producers = models.ManyToManyField(Producer)
```

I can imagine a lot of the possible way to compare these fields would be very slow, because they load all the objects of the ManyToMany fields before comparing.
Is there a quick way to count matches based on id's?

My current way to check is:

```
in_common = len(set(song_one.genres.all()) & set(song_two.genres.all()))
```

Comment: I would however advice counting all the matching relations in a single query, since this will result in three `JOIN`s, the `JOIN`s will thus start acting like a *multiplier*, making the query very inefficienty.

Comment: So `Song.objects.filter(genres__song=song).annotate(match_genre=Count('genres'))` will annotate every other song with the number of matching genres with `song`.